# Implementer Iterator

Tags: java, iterator

I am currently trying to implement Iterator which receives a collection and a char and that yields the
Strings that starts with that char.
So I ended up with the following (working) code:

```
class A {
public static void main (String [] args) {
    String [] arr = {"abcd","gr","gres","bvg","bb"};
    
    class FirstCharIt implements Iterator<String> {
        char c;
        private Iterator<String> it;
        public FirstCharIt (Collection<String> lst,char c) {
            this.c = c;
            this.it = lst.stream().filter(x->{
                return (x.charAt(0)==this.c);
            }).iterator();
        }
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return it.hasNext();
        }

        @Override
        public String next() {
            return it.next();
        }
        
        public Iterator<String> get () {
            return it;
        }
    }
    
    FirstCharIt it1 = new FirstCharIt(Arrays.asList(arr),'b');
    for (it1.get();it1.hasNext();) {
        System.out.println(it1.next());
    }
}
```

}

Although this code is working this is not actually *implementing* Iterator interface and I even can remove the 'implements Iterator' from my class headline.
And of course the method `get` wasn't there in more *right* implementation

So I would like to have some advice about what I did here,
thanks

Comment: There's no need to implement your own iterator class if you're already using Streams. Just return a `stream.map(…).iterator()` instance.

Comment: "Although this code is working this is not actually implementing Iterator interface" - yes it does. "and I even can remove the 'implements Iterator' from my class headline`" - that statement is true for any class that implements any interface, so I'm not sure why you mention it.

Comment: @Eran : what I mean is that if, for instance, I have method that's arguments are
1.List<String> l, 2.Iterator<String> i
then if I'll remove the 'implements..' part from my class it wouldn't pass compilation.

Comment: @AndyTurner,Miha_x64
Yes I got that. but what is the way to change my code to have normal Iterator class?

Comment: Do you mean to have `for(String nxt: it1){...}` Maybe you want to implement `Iterable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter the input list at initialization, have that filtered collection and an index as fields of your iterator.

Have `hasNext()` check if the index has reached the end of the filtered collection, and `next()` increase the index and return the element it previously pointed at.

```
static class FirstCharIt implements Iterator<String> {
    private int currentIndex;
    private List<String> filtered;
    public FirstCharIt (List<String> coll, char letter) {
        this.filtered = coll.stream().filter(x->x.startsWith(""+letter)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        this.currentIndex = 0;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return currentIndex < filtered.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String next() {
        if (!hasNext()) { throw new NoSuchElementException(); }
        return filtered.get(currentIndex++);
    }
}
```

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/EhTH6z).

Comment: This is closer towards what I was looking for. TY Aaron